# Model class image disappears on mouse-over

Tags: visual-studio-2008, entity-framework

I have just added an Entity Framework model to my console project in VS 2008, but when my mouse pointer moves over the only class in the model, in the model designer, the graphic for that class becomes invisible.  Anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that this was a known issue when installed on some early versions of Windows 7.

If that sounds like you then...

The workaround is to scroll around the canvas, if I remember correctly